# AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python

[pls help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z66xt.png)

i need help with an error AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'Client'

Comment: `Client` is a member of the `discord` module directly.  It is not a member of `discord.ext.commands`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a Discord client object to use the Discord API use:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
```

Client is not part of discord.ext.commands, therefore your import is resulting in an error.